# DataTables TableTools with Bootstrap on Multiple Tables

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, zeroclipboard, tabletools

I have multiple tables displayed in one web page, being initialized by below code:

```
/* Tables initialisation */
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.dataTable').dataTable({
    "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span3'T><'span3'i><'span6'p>>",
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "bStateSave": true,
    "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
    },
    "oTableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.4/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
        "aButtons": [ "copy", "csv", "xls", "pdf", "print" ]
    }
});
});
```

There is no javascript error in both Chrome or Safari, nevertheless when clicking on any of the buttons, it just doesn't work. Please help me debug / figure out what's wrong!

Comment: The example I'm talking about can be found here: http://www.awsnow.info :)

Comment: Which buttons are you referring to? There's a whole load of them in that page :)

Answer (score 0):

Never-mind! Apparently it's working now and it always did. I realized it after reading this post: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/15605/even-tabletool-examples-are-not-working :)

Comment: _If you are using file:// you need to add a security exception to the Flash player to allow file export and copy to clipboard. That's just how Flash works, I'm afraid - nothing I can do about it._